# printing a matrix in a special form python

Tags: python, matrix

I need to write a function that when given a matrix from an input will read and print the matrix based upon a special order. the code should print the matrix by going around the boarder clockwise. so for example if the matrix is

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[1 2 3 4 5]
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

it would output the list

```
1,2,3,4,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1
```

i know it will require a for loop, so i have created the for loop that will print the first line but i don't know how to go from there. i feel like i have to define the final number of each list in the matrix as something like n-1 where n is the length

Comment: So you want to traverse the boundary numbers?! Looks like a school assignment to me, so try to make it work and come back here when you have sample code which almost works.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a simple one-liner:

```
>>> m = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
>>> print((lambda M:[m[p[1]][p[0]]for p in sorted([(x,y)for x in range(len(m[0]))for y in range(len(m))if x in(0,len(m[0])-1)or y in(0,len(m)-1)],key=lambda p:M.atan2(len(m)/2.0-p[1],len(m[0])/2.0-p[0])+(2*M.pi if M.atan2(len(m)/2.0-p[1],len(m[0])/2.0-p[0])<M.atan2(len(m)/2.0,len(m[0])/2.0)else 0))])(__import__("math")))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: *Simply...magnificent...*

Comment: I wouldn't call it "simple" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Indexing a python list with -1 will return the last element of the list, so there is no need to think about `n-1`.

`reversed` returns a generator that returns the elements of the provided iterable in reversed order without creating a copy of the argument.

```
m=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

def get_edges(M):
    res = M[0]
    for l in M[1:-1]:
        res.append(l[-1])
    res += reversed(M[-1])
    for l in reversed(M[1:-1]):
        res.append(l[0])

    return res


print get_edges(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```
data =[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
for i in range(len(data[0])):
    print data[0][i]
for i in range(1,len(data)-1):
    print data[i][len(data[i])-1]
for i in range(len(data[len(data)-1])-1,0,-1):
    print data[len(data)-1][i]
for i in range((len(data)-1),0,-1):
    print data[i][0]
```

Comment: this was super helpful, i was having alot of difficulty conceptualizing how i would index the matrix in such a way that only the last number would be received and i see now how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient way for sure but it works
and is somewhat pythonic.

```
#matrix is represented as list of list form for simplicity
matrix = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]  


def find_border(matrix):
    result=[]

    #printing up
    for i in matrix[0][:-1]:  #Slicing the first row to exclude the last element
        result.append(i)

    #right
    for row in matrix:
        result.append(row[-1]) #Getting last element of each row

    #down
    for i in list(reversed(matrix[-1]))[:-1]: #Iterating the last row in reversed order and leaving the 1st element of last row
        result.append(i)

    #left
    for row in reversed(matrix): #Iterating through rows in reversed , getting first element
        result.append(row[0])

    print(",".join([str(i) for i in result])) #Printing result in whatever manner required

find_border(matrix)
```